# I am getting blank user_intrest from facebook in my ios app.

Tags: ios, iphone

I am using graph api for getting user_intrests field. But it is returning blank everytime.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `/user/interests` API endpoint instead of `user_intrests`.

N.B. `user_interests` permission is required to return interests

Comment: Have you added 'user_interests' in permissions?

Comment: yes i have added. If i am admin of facebook app on developer portal then i still needed first app review to get user intrests??

Comment: If i am admin of facebook app and i am login with same id in my app. Then i dont think i need review of my app to get user_intrests.